# Maximal interval of existence of an exact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following exact differential equation

$$y' = \frac{\dfrac{2x}{y}+\dfrac{3x^2}{y^2}-3}{\dfrac{x^2}{y^2}+\dfrac{2x^3}{y^3}}$$

and the initial condition $y(1)=1$. I solved it and obtained $$\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{x^3}{y^2}-3x=C$$

The maximal interval I am supposed to find is $\left(\frac13, \infty\right)$.
How do I get to the $\frac13$?

My impression was that I needed to find the values of y for which the denominator equals zero without having to solve the ODE, but I don't know how to do it since I can't find an implicit expression of $y(x)$.

Comment: Observe that $x=1/3$ is the value for which $-3 x =C$.

Comment: When $y$ blows up at a finite time, the terms involving $y$ become zero so you have $-3x=C$.

Comment: By the way you can in fact finish solving it for $y$ explicitly from there. Doing so does not help that much but still.